# I want my PHP email code to redirect to a page once its done

Tags: php

I've got a PHP email script working fine but ideally what I want is instead of a message saying:

> Thank you for contacting CF Racing F3, we will be in touch with you very soon.

I want it to redirect to a url, here's the code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "number8pie@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "CFR F3 Contact Form";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['message'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $message = $_POST['message']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  }
  if(strlen($message) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Message you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

Thank you for contacting CF Racing F3, we will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a header redirect by changing this:

```
?>

Thank you for contacting CF Racing F3, we will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
?>
```

To this:

```
header( "Location: http://www.example.com/email_done.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the following statement:

```
header("Location: http://www.test.com/test.php");
```

Make sure you do not output or print anything before this line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect after sending an email then you can use

```
if(mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)){
header( "Location: http://www.example.com/email_success.php");
}
```

And add message in email_success.php

```
Thank you for contacting CF Racing F3, we will be in touch with you very soon.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to redirect to another page once the mail has been successfully sent:

```
if (mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)) {
    header("Location: http://your_domain.com/your_page.php");
}
```